# Gradle sync failed: Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 69

Tags: android, git, macos, android-studio

In Android Studio, when I try to build the ODKCollect project, the build fails during the gradle sync stage with the `Gradle sync failed: Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 69 error.` I checked in the Android preferences and it's pointing to a working git executable. When I tried to build the same code a little while ago, it was working... Mac, Yosemite, git xcode build.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently this error was thrown because I hadn't signed the Xcode EULA. Once I opened xcode and signed that, all started working. Thanks to this [link.](https://mythinkpond.com/2015/09/24/solved-git-status-failed-with-code-69-error-when-opening-sourcetree-in-mac-os-x/)

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me!